# How to use *ngFor to create table and access elements with just indexes?

Tags: php, angular, html-table, ngfor

I am making a front-end for my PHP project using Angular and I want to make a HTML table, with specified width and height, using just *ngFor and indexes and show items of an one-dimensional array. I have a PHP code that looks like this:

```
$items = array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"); // belongs in .ts file

// belongs in .html file
echo "<table>";

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";

    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        echo "<td>" . $items[$i * 3 + $j] . "</td>";
    }
    
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>
```

How do I do this in Angular? `*ngFor="let item in items"` is Angular equivalent to `foreach ($items as item)`, which is a thing that I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an index like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  {{i}}
</tr>
```

And manipulate the outcome depending what you are trying achieve, above I've just listed all the indexes of the items array. You can also nest a loop inside, and control which element to show or hide(they wont be in the DOM Object) with *ngIf:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <td *ngFor="let detail of details; index as i>
    <ng-container *ngIf="X"
      //where X is anything that returns a boolean, a variable, function or even truthy value
       {{detail}}
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular *ngFor always iterate over arrays, there' **no** any like `for (i=0;i<10;i++)`

But you can create the array in the own .html

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let i of [0,1]">
    <td *ngFor="let j of [0,1,2]">
       {{{items[i*3+j]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

NOTE: Really you can also create a directive that simulate a php for, see e.g. this [old post about it](https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-structural-directives-in-angular-bfe4d8c44fb1)

NOTE2: I use simply items, not $items because in Angular is common use the $ in variables only when the variable is an observable